# How to get a pushed parse object as soon as possible into my app

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am not getting any idea about getting a pushed object as soon as possible into my app.
Like I push my location from a device to parse cloud and at the same moment when the object was uploaded I want to retrieve the object into another device in which my app is installed.
Whenever a new object arrives at parse cloud I want it should be sent to the other device.If I say simply I want some monitoring method for new arrival of data and retrieve it.